# Bluetooth Android and Bluetooth iOS

Tags: bluetooth, android-bluetooth, ios-bluetooth

When I press a button on a device that is connected to iOS or Android via Bluetooth, it should perform some task in an app(app installed on iOS or Android). I am not sure which Bluetooth profile will be best for my job. I think HID profile, but will it work with iOS ? Any suggestions or comments are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

iOS devices can't use standard Bluetooth connection with Android.  In this case you should use BLE (Bluetooth Low Energy).  This means you should use GATT profile for Android.  There is an important issue here: all iOS devices can BLE peripheral or central but for Android some devices only can peripheral.

Comment: Can you add more information why iOS can't use standard Bluetooth with Android? Is Bluetooth iOS specific?